# BLE data transfer speed

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, react-native-ble-plx

I am trying to know what is the maximum data transfer speed between an Android mobile phone and a BLE peripheral.

Wikipedia indicates that this is "125 kbit/s – 1 Mbit/s – 2 Mbit/s" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy#Technical_details)

However, I tried to implement a POC, with a BLE peripheral sending 20-bytes notifications every 10 ms (which should lead to a data transfer speed of 16 kbit/s), and a mobile app subscribing to these notifications. I only get a fraction of the emitted notifications (10%, which is 1600 bit/s). If I increase the number of notifications sent, the number of notifications received does not increase (sometimes, it even decreases).

My tests were done using [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) for the mobile phone and [react-native-ble-peripheral](https://github.com/himelbrand/react-native-ble-peripheral) for the fake BLE peripheral.

**How can I do to achieve a 1 Mbit/s data transfer speed with a BLE peripheral?**

Comment: Please see https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-speed-maximum-throughput/.

Comment: This is another useful article:- https://punchthrough.com/maximizing-ble-throughput-on-ios-and-android/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the BLE data transfer speed. However, you can request an increase of the Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) i.e. the the largest packet size, specified in bytes that can be sent between your BLE center and peripheral:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    bluetoothGatt.requestMtu(mtu);
}
```

Then handle the response in your `BluetoothGattCallback`'s

```
@Override
public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {

}
```